# How to mock a function defined with this keyword using sinon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon

I have a function foo

```
var foo = function(){
    this.doRandomStuff = function(callback){
      //do Something
      callback(false);
    }
}
var bar = function(){
    var fooInstance = new foo();
    fooInstance.doRandomStuff(function(val){
      //do Something with val
    })
}
```

I want to write test for bar function and I am using mocha and sinon for this.

```
describe("Foo Test",function(){
      it("testing foo",function(done){
         var instance = new foo();

         sinon.stub(instance,'doRandomStuff').callsArgWith(0,true); // This Doesn't work
         sinon.stub(foo,'doRandomStuff').callsArgWith(0,true); // This also Doesn't work

         bar();
         done();
      })
});
```

I get below Exception :

> TypeError: Cannot stub non-existent own property doRandomStuff

Comment: you can't test this code. you are creating new instance of foo in bar function. so you don't have access of this for that instance. to make it testable you can pass instance of foo to bar function.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach to make it more testable is module approach as below:

**foo.js**

```
function doRandomStuff(callback) {
  callback(false);
}

module.exports = {
  doRandomStuff
}
```

**bar.js**

```
const foo = require('./foo');

module.exports = function() {
  foo.doRandomStuff(function(val) {
    console.log('test val', val); // for testing purpose
  })
}
```

**test.js**

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
const foo = require('./foo');
const bar = require('./bar');

describe('Foo Test', function() {
  it("testing foo",function(done){
    sinon.stub(foo, 'doRandomStuff').callsArgWith(0,true); 

    bar(); // output: "test val true"
    done();
 });
});
```